# Segmentation Fault in VSC within while loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm attempting to make a hangman game in C. I encountered this segmentation fault at the first line of this code block.

```
while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
        int i = 0;

        char buf[LEN];
        FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
        struct diction_t *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(struct diction_t));
        assert(dictionary);

        dictionary->nval = INIT;
        dictionary->max = INIT;
        dictionary->words = NULL;
        /* uses doubling reallocation system */
        while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
                if (dictionary->words == NULL) {
                        dictionary->words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
                        assert(dictionary->words);
                } else if (dictionary->nval > dictionary->max) {
                        dictionary->words = realloc(dictionary->words, GROW * dictionary->max *sizeof(char *));
                        assert(dictionary->words);
                        dictionary->max = GROW * dictionary->max;
                }
                dictionary->words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN);
                assert(dictionary->words[i]);

                strncpy(dictionary->words[i], strtok(buf, "\n"), LEN);
                i++;
                dictionary->nval++;
        }
        dictionary->nval--;
        fclose(fp);

        return dictionary;
}
```

Never encountered this before so I honestly do not know where to look. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You never check if `fopen` succeeds or not. Very likely the file isn't in the location you believe, and it will fail. Try using an absolute path to the file. And add a check to make sure `fopen` succeeds before using `fp`.

Comment: what is `struct diction_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation to your problem is that on the line

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
```

the function call to `fopen` failed, so that `fp` gets the value `NULL`. Therefore, when you attempt to use this invalid value `NULL` on the line

```
while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {
```

you get a segmentation fault.

For this reason, I suggest that you replace the line

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
```

with the following code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
if ( fp == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Error: Unable to open file!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

My guess is that after performing that change, instead of getting a segmentation fault, you will now get the error message:

```
Error: Unable to open file!
```

The most common reason for this kind of failure is that the file does not exist in the current working directory.

Although the ISO C standard does not require this, on most platforms, `fopen` sets `errno` to indicate the reason for the failure. In order to print out this reason if it is provided by the platform, you can add `#include <errno.h>` to the top of the file and use the following code instead:

```
errno = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
if ( fp == NULL )
{
    if ( errno == 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error: Unable to open file!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        perror( "Error opening file" );
    }
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Comment: I ended up moving the file into the correct directory, thought it was already in there but guess not. However, now i'm getting another fault at a line further down in the same block. The line that has "strncpy(dictionary->words[i], strtok(buf, "\n"), LEN);"

Comment: @IV6IX: My guess is that `strtok` is returning `NULL`, which you are then passing to `strncpy`, which causes your program to cause a segmentation fault. Therefore, I suggest that you check the return value of `strtok` before passing the returned value to `strncpy`.

Comment: So, 'strtok' doesn't have a return value. Is that what I need to do then to fix it is give it one? This is the only instance it is used in the code

Comment: @IV6IX: The function `strtok` **does** have a return value. It returns a pointer to the next token, or `NULL` if there is no next token. In this case, you appear to be using `strtok` only to remove the newline character, but if the line is empty, then it will not give you a pointer to an empty string, but will rather simply return `NULL`. Therefore, I do not recommend using `strtok` for this purpose. Instead, I recommend that you simply pass `buf` instead of `strtok(buf, "\n")` to the function `strncpy` and remove the newline character beforehand, using `buf[strcspn[buf,"\n"] = '\0';`.

Comment: @IV6IX: See the following question for further information on how to remove the newline character from the result of `fgets`: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471) Note that you will have to `#include <string.h>` to use that function.

Comment: @IV6IX: Also, beware that using the function `strncpy` can be extremely dangerous, because if there is not enough space to write the entire string, then the written string will not be terminated by a null character. This will likely cause a segmentation fault if you later treat that string as if it were null-terminated.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for all your help. I also found it weird since my code works on an online c compiler but not in VSC.